# R detect numerical length pattern and add hyphen

Tags: r, regex

I have the following types of addresses. I'd like to add a hyphen if the first two numbers conform to an exact length.

So if address pattern looks like the following: {2} {3}, then add a "-" between the two numbers:

`12 123 SESAME ST.`

`12-123 SESAME ST.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
str <- "12 123 SESAME ST."
gsub("\\b(\\d{2}) (\\d{3})\\b","\\1-\\2", str)
# [1] "12-123 SESAME ST."
```

The "\d{}" parts match a digit a certain number of times and the "()" capture those matches. The "\b" part makes sure that those patterns occur at word boundaries. Then during the replacement, the "\1 and "\2" parts refer to the captured portions of the match and we just stick a dash in the middle.